# Why were taxiways marked with numbers (as opposed to letters) back in the day?

Tags: aviation-history, runways, ground-operations, taxiing, taxiways

I learned through the [USAir Flight 1493 and SkyWest Airlines Flight 5569 collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_runway_disaster) that many taxiways at KLAX were marked with numbers (e.g., Taxiway 45, Taxiway 33) instead of letters (e.g., Taxiway B [bravo]). Below is a snippet of the airport diagram effective at the time of the accident.

[image]

Why were numbers used back then, and why has it changed to letters exclusively?

Comment: I would bet good money that it's a) because people usually number things when they want to be able to refer to them b) because they found out it's easier to confuse taxiway 17 with runway 17, and less easy to confuse taxiway Bravo with runway 17

Comment: *"why has it changed to letters exclusively?"* not exclusively. In some airports there are taxiways designated with [letter][number], usually for "stub" taxiways. See https://www.skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/3172.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This memorandum on taxi way nomenclature states](https://www.skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/3172.pdf)

> 1. Numbers by themselves, and the letters "I" and "O" **must not be used
>    because they could be mistaken for a runway number**.
> 2. The letter "X"
>    must not be used because a sign with an "X" could be misconstrued as
>    indicating a closed taxiway or runway.

Not only are they lettered but I,O, and X are not permissible. Its also worth noting that numbers *can* be used in some cases

> After all available single and double-same alphabet letters have been
> utilized, taxiways should use two-character alphanumeric designations
> such as “A1.” (See Figure 1a) The numeric character used should be a
> single digit from 1 to 9. (See paragraph f for the use of twodigit
> designators).

Answer (score 1):

The system was changed to prevent confusion of runway numbers with taxiway numbers.